# Can a subscription product be shared among different apps?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am building a spinoff of my app, basically a "better accessibility" version of the app. (Main targeted at young adults, spinoff targeted at senior citizens).

The spinoff app will have it's own app id (com.mycompany.myapp vs com.mycompany.accessibilityapp). 
Therefore it will have it's own store page and can technically be installed alongside the main app.

Here's the tough part. On the main app I have a "subscription for premium featured" model. And I want it so that from the spinoff I can check if the user already has a subscription from the main app to unlock these features, and vice-versa.

Is there any way to check, from the spinoff app, if the user has a subscription on the main app?

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved if the 2 apps share the same database (or just data).

That way any new user from either app can be kept together in a common shared node and the user's "subscribed" boolean property can be accessible and verifiable by both the apps.

Hope this is not too vague.